# Are tea-related questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Apparently [tea contains more caffeine than coffee](http://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-25502,00.html). Does it mean tea questions can be on topic?

Comment: Just to note, we didn't create this site based on caffeine content, otherwise chocolate, energy drinks, and many nutritional supplements would be on topic.

Comment: See also [the original discussion from Area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/12394/120719) where the decision was made to *not* include tea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

But there's an Area 51 [Proposal for beverages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105491/beverages)!

Answer (score 8):

## No

But there's an [Area 51 Proposal for tea](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72875/tea)!

Comment: @kenorb - See also [the original discussion from Area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/12394/120719) where the decision was made to *not* include tea.

Comment: Also tea is on topic on http://cooking.stackexchange.com, so you don't have to wait for that proposal to launch. (It might be quite a while given how early it is in the Area51 process.)

Comment: @hoc_age That might be true, but honestly, the reasoning given for not including tea is pretty silly. He lists 5 things, all of which share many similarities in tea expertise. It honestly seems like a petty distinction. Quite frankly, it's very possible the site will not be able to continue without the additional activity from allowing other brewed beverages. We went through the same thing with SQA and Selenium, and many of the single-focus sites either have folded or are struggling mightily for activity.